# Write data into the file on the disk and then fonud file's md5 is not write?

Tags: android, c++, fwrite

it happens in the android client and  it's Small probability.the code just  like this:

```
bool WriteAndVerify(unsigned char* pvData,int dwLength){


if (!FileVerifyData(pvData,1 dwLength))
{
    return false;
}
if (!fwrite(pvData,1, dwLength,stream))
{
 return false;
}
//fflush(); no fllush
}
```

the code is very simple ,verify and write.but in small probability the final file is broken.i compare the final file to the right file,they have 64k or 128k bit data difference.and the wrong data looks like other's proccess's data.

my question :any posibility can cause this? it just happen in android,i found a android phone is HuaWei and it has external TF Card.

the buffer length is 16K,i have two idea:
1.any the other buffer stack overflow,and fllush my data
2.maybe physics address map into virtual addrees system wrong in two TF card phone

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using the old C functions to handle your files? Why not the C++ streams?

Comment: More related to your problem, what if your `FileVerifyData` function doing? What does it really "verify"? And the name `WriteAndVerify` is kind of misleading, since you do it in the other order (you *first* "verify" and *then* you write).

Comment: You commented out the fflush call .. why? That makes at least an _attempt_ to put bytes on disk. For all we know you data is stuck in a buffer waiting for you to flush or close.

Comment: `data looks like other's proccess's data` looks like you writing trash from memory. I'm guessing that end of file is handled incorrectly when file size is not a multiplication of your buffer size. Anyway you posted only fraction of code needed to understand your problem. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: FileVerifyData just does somethind MD5 proccess ,the flow is checking buffer and write buffer.
i know the 'fflush' op can fllush buffer into the disk,i don't know wheather this is the reason,my code didn't have fflush op;

i down know where is the dity data from,the file broken position is in the mid of file and the offset is an integer multiple of 16K。Code is very simple just like code i give above.

Comment: Without a [mre] it's going to be really hard to help you. Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.